# Error on classwork

Tags: java

I am getting an error with my code, how can I go about fixing this. Basically whats the best (entry level) way to pull the second character out of a string if it is there.

EDIT: error is

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: 
        String index out of range: 1
    at java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:686)
    at RomanNumeral.main(RomanNumeral.java:38)
```

My code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class RomanNumeral {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Declare Variable
        int total = 0, length = 0;
        int first;
        int second;
        String romanNumerals;

        // Declare Scanner
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        // Get Input
        System.out.println("Please input a Roman Numeral: ");

        romanNumerals = in.next();

        length = romanNumerals.length();

        while (length != 0) {
            first = valueFinder(romanNumerals.charAt(0));

            if (length > 1) {
                second = valueFinder(romanNumerals.charAt(1));
            } else {
                second = 0;
            }

            if (first >= second || length == 1) {
                total += first;
                romanNumerals = romanNumerals.substring(1);
                System.out.println(romanNumerals);
            }// End of if
            else {
                total += (second - first);
                romanNumerals = romanNumerals.substring(2);
                System.out.println(romanNumerals);
            }// End of Else

        }// End of loop
        System.out.println(total);

    }// End of Main Method

    // valueFinder Method

    public static int valueFinder(char numeral) {
        int value = 0;
        switch (numeral) {
            case 'I':
                value = 1;
                break;
            case 'V':
                value = 5;
                break;
            case 'X':
                value = 10;
                break;
            case 'L':
                value = 50;
                break;
            case 'C':
                value = 100;
                break;
            case 'D':
                value = 500;
                break;
            case 'M':
                value = 1000;
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println(numeral 
                                + " is not a Roman Numeral, and will be ignored.");
                break;
        }// End of Switch
        return value;

    }// End of Method

}// End of Class
```

Comment: Can you post the error..?  It'd help out.

Comment: @Pnchappy92: I edited your question to improve the formatting. Just for future reference, you can highlight a block of code in your question and use the buttons above the text box to format the code automatically.

Answer (score 3):

You need to update your `length` variable after taking the substring of `romanNumerals`.  The string itself is getting shorter as you substring it, but the number you refer to as its length is not.  It would be simpler to just call the string.length() method when you need it, as it would remove the need to maintain your `length` variable.

Alternatively, make another method that will modify both the string and the length counter (name it something like `subStringAndUpdateLength()`).  But that would be overkill.